# Why JavaScript is not working in HTTPS on my site

Tags: javascript, https

I have just added HTTPS to my site and apparently the only script I have on my site has stopped working. I don't think it is a problem of the script, but here it is:

```
function cambiarPestanna(pestannas, pestanna) {

    pestanna = document.getElementById(pestanna.id);
    listaPestannas = document.getElementById(pestannas.id);

    cpestanna = document.getElementById('c' + pestanna.id);
    listacPestannas = document.getElementById('contenido' + pestannas.id);

    i = 0;
    while (typeof listacPestannas.getElementsByTagName('div')[i] != 'undefined') {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(listacPestannas.getElementsByTagName('div')[i]).css('display', 'none');
            $(listaPestannas.getElementsByTagName('li')[i]).css('background', '');
            $(listaPestannas.getElementsByTagName('li')[i]).css('padding-bottom', '');
        });
        i += 1;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(cpestanna).css('display', '');
        $(pestanna).css('background', 'white');
        $(pestanna).css('padding-bottom', '2px');
    });

}
```

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you use chrome dev tool and found any errors?

Comment: how you included this script file,  show the `<script>` tag code

Comment: The script must also be loaded via HTTPS.

Comment: It says: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: its unable to load jQuery library, so it stopped right there remove `http:` part in src of jquery import

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="cambiarPestanna.js"></script>

Comment: ok.. this one's fine, how about jquery include

Comment: @vinayakj thank you! It was because of that:   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: What are the parameters to that function?  That code is seriously in need of a rewrite; it's a mess.  Why the combination of jQuery with native DOM calls? Why the "ready" handlers in the `while` loop?

Comment: @alfuco yeah.. I also added sample in below answer.. take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your jQuery file like this, without mentioning the protocol explicitly:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Removing the `http:` part from `src` means you don't want to load external files/resources with a fixed protocol that you are mentioning in the `src`. Rather, you want to load the external resources with the same protocol the demanding resource is residing in.

Answer (score 0):

Load all the scripts on you page this way:

`<script src="//domain.com/path/script.js"></script>`

The main part is `//` – it tells the browser to use the current protocol – HTTPS in your case.

For example, the last version of jQuery from the CDN:

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`