# d3.js Broke when an SSL was added

Tags: d3.js

I added an SSL to my site and now the d3.js interactive map I had working disappears. When I remove the https the map works fine, but if I load the site via https the map disappears. Any help here would be awesome!
link to problem page:
no issue: http://endhungerct.org
with the issue: https://endhungerct.org

You will see the map on the no issue link and it is gone on the with issue link.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Javascript is not working in https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322189/javascript-is-not-working-in-https)

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears because, you are trying to request unsecured information from a secure page.

The [json](http://www.endhungerct.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ct.topo.json) http://www.endhungerct.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ct.topo.json wich is used to load the map is hosted on http.

You are should change the request to use also https.